# modify and add one more condition in controller with cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have this condition in controller where I am listing products from one table

```
$conditions = array('winner_id >' => 0, 'Product.beg' => '1', 'Product.status_id' => $status_id);
```

I need to add one more condition here to check that which winner have paid also. So I have one more table accounts, and I have winner id in products table. So how will I add condition here that it will check winners id in accounts table also in same condition.

Need to add only one condition more, that take winner_id from Product table and search it in Accounts table, and show only those id's which is there in Accounts table

I tried this way but not working:

```
$conditions = array('winner_id >' => 0, 'Product.beg' => '1', 'Product.status_id' => $status_id, array('conditions' => array('Product.winner_id' => $this->'Account.user_id')));
```

Answer (score 1):

if based on some `if` condition you want to add to `condition` this could help.. Correct me if i have missed something.

```
if(condition)
{
    $conditions + = array('field_name' => 'field_value');
}
```